# How filtered unique values by one filed?

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I would like get from database unique values by one field and between two dates

My entity fields Visit:

> - id
> - guestId
> - date

I have some method and I would like to get list of Visit by unique field "guestId":

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT v FROM Visit v WHERE  v.date BETWEEN :start AND :to")
    List<Visit> getBetween(@Param("start") Date start, @Param("to") Date to);
```

but I get list with all entity by this period.

I tried query:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT  FROM visits WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :to"
```

but it doesn't work too.

For example:

Example of table "visits":

```
 Id     GuestId    Date  
 100    200        2019.09.07 
 101    201        2019.09.07 
 102    200        2019.09.07 
 103    201        2019.09.08 
 104    201        2019.09.08 
 105    200        2019.09.08 
 106    201        2019.09.09 
 107    201        2019.09.09 
 108    200        2019.09.09
```

next I would like to do query

> SELECT DISTINCT  FROM visits WHERE  date BETWEEN :'2019.09.08' AND
>   :'2019.09.08'"

And I want to get list of:

```
GuestId    Date  
201        2019.09.08  
200        2019.09.08
```

Please help me find execute query

Thanks.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: Why not `SELECT DISTINCT guestId FROM...`?

Comment: example of table added to description

Comment: "SELECT DISTINCT guestId FROM visits WHERE  date BETWEEN :start AND :to"
doesn't work, i get Exeption

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.java.library.repository.DataJpaRepository.getBetween(java.util.Date,java.util.Date)!

Comment: Because your entity is named Visit, not visits. And you must use an alias: `select distinct v.guestId from Visit v where v.date between :start and :to`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create class with `guestId` and `date` fields and use a native query, like:

```
class DistinctVisitView {
    Integer guestId;
    LocalDate date;
}

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT DISTINCT guest_id, date FROM visits WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :to")
List<DistinctVisitView> getBetween(@Param("start") Date start, @Param("to") Date to);
```